# Unique Constraint - Symfony2 and Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, unique-constraint

I couldn't find documentation with this written in a way I can understand it, so I'm asking you for help. This question is related to [Unique entity - Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616342/unique-entity-symfony2)

I have a table called **category** with three fields - **id**, **fos_user_id** and **name**.
The other table is called **fos_user** and has fields id, username and so on.

I want categories to be unique for user. One user can't have two ctegories with name "Food", but all of the users can have category called "Food".

In the other question I was adviced to try something like this:

```
* @ORM\Table(name="categories",
*            uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="name_user_id__idx", 
*                                                     columns={"name", "user_id"})})
```

and I tried this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", 
 *              uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="name_user_idx",                                                     
                                           columns={"name", "fos_user_id"})}))
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\BudgetTrackerBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "fos_user_id"}, message="There already is such a category.")
 */
```

but I get this error:

> The field 'fos_user_id' is not mapped by Doctrine, so it cannot be validated for uniqueness.

I can't quite understand the error. And I don't understand the part with the constraints. Is this the right syntax and the right thing to write?

Thank you very much in advance!

PS : Sorry for opening a new question, if I shouldn't, but I added a lot of new things and decided that a new qusetion is better than editing the old one and asking in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

For relations like Category, User etc... you should not use unique constraints on columns but on relations. For example:

instead of

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "fos_user_id"})
```

try

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "user"})
```

where "user" is the name of mapped field to relation with User entity.

Comment: I changed what you said, but it still doesn't allow two users to have a category with the same name.

Comment: I removed it, all I have now is `@UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "user"})`, but now it doesn't let different users to have categories with the same name.

Comment: Can you check that you don't have -any- other @Unique.... annotation left somewhere? Or in parent class if you have one. If not, try this: @UniqueEntity(fields={"id", "name", "user"}) although I am not sure that would work.

Comment: `@UniqueEntity(fields={"name", "user"})` works when I'm editing an existing item, but it doesn't validate when I'm adding new items. It isn't too bad to write a method which counts how many categories there are for this user with this name, and to validate based on its answer, is it?

Comment: It is not bad thing to do it manually, I am just suprised that it doesn't work by default. Oh well... Nothing is perfect, not even Symfony :)

Comment: Oh, I'm pretty sure it's my fault that it doesn't work, but I couldn't find what's wrong because it works when editting and doesn't work when adding new items. However, I'll do it manually. Thanks for your help and concern! :)

Comment: I know the question is old but this might help others too. Make sure you have all the needed data set on the object before you call `$form->submit()` or `$form->handleRequest()` because that's what does the form submission and validation. If you change any data on the object after you called the form submission function, it will not be validated again hence `$form->isValid()` will still be `true` even though you invalidated the form after submission. I had the exact same issue and solved it by setting all necessary data on the object before calling `$form->handleRequest()`.